# Unable to include ux in Ext JS application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

The application does not include the UX.
The entire extjs library is in -  `myexample/js/ext-6.2.0`
I copied from `myexample/js/ext-6.2.0/` packages the folder "ux" with all the contents into my application

```
test
|---app.js
|
|---app
|    |---controller
|    |---model
|    |---store
|    |---ux 
|    |---view
|---index.html
```

Then in app.js, before calling the application I connect 'ux':

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'app/ux');
Ext.application({
....
```

I get the error:

> [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'widget.treepicker'; consider
>   adding Ext.require('widget.treepicker') above Ext.onReady

Version: Ext JS 6.2.0.981 - JavaScript Library

What am I doing wrong?
How to incldue UX?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this in the app.js file

```
requires:[
    'Ext.ux.your_file_name' //your_file_name inside the ux folder
]
```

Comment: Only when I copied the TreePicker.js file from ux / classic / src to the folder with the application, was it possible to connect it

Comment: i dint find app.json in extjs 4.2.2 , how can i fix this issue in extjs 4.2.2?

Comment: its app.js file not app.json

Answer (score 1):

In file "app.json" you should find "requires" config similar to this

```
 "requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "charts",
        "ux"
    ]
```

"app.json" will be present in Extjs application folder, this folder will be the result of command :

```
sencha generate app -ext MyApp /path/to/my-app
```

This is where you import the package. So part of your code is making "ext" package to be not loaded. This is causing error related to "treepicker". Because "treepicker" is part of "extjs" package.
Try including package this way. It should work.

Comment: where is the app.json file?

Comment: It'll be present in application folder of Extjs application. There would be a folder created when you run " sencha app generate ". It'll be present in that folder.

Comment: When creating applications, I downloaded and decoupled extjs on the server, and then in my application's index.php, I include the necessary files from the extjs package.
Do I understand correctly that I now need to install sencha cmd, and then generate a new application?

Comment: yes its good to access packages from application rather than direct, because application bootstrap will take care of lot of things including the problem which you are facing.

Comment: But I don’t understand one thing, I’ve already created an application, what exactly do I need to do after installing sencha cmd

Comment: If application is created already then you should find "app.json" in application folder.

Comment: I created the structure of my application manually: controller, model, store, view and files that are inside folders, as well as app.js and index.php

Comment: Then you can add "app.json" yourself. For its contents generate another dummy application using sencha cmd.

Comment: It turns out that I can manually create the app.json file after I install sencha cmd on my server. If so, what kind of content and its location should it be?

Comment: That command which I showed will create the application folder. This will have "app.json" , you'll get the contents in this file.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what to do

Comment: i dint find app.json in extjs 4.2.2 , how can i fix this issue in extjs 4.2.2?