# Is there a minified file for Ext.UX package? just like ext-all?

Tags: extjs, minify, extjs4.2

I want to use livesearchgridpanel component which is there in Ext.ux package ,
is there a minified file like ux-all.js for this package? just like ext-all.js ?
I am using Extjs 4.2.2 version

Comment: i saw
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879264/unable-to-include-ux-in-ext-js-application
but in extjs 422 , i dint find appjson file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, extjs 4 has no builded ux package. But you can do this self with help your CI or  Sencha CMD(look at build.xml in sdk). Ext JS 4 hasn't `app.json` - it appeared in 5 version

EDIT

Also you can build ux package with help next command:

```
sencha compile exclude --all and include --class 'Ext.ux.*' and concatenate --compress ./ext-ux.js
```

Run this command on root sdk.

Possible config for build sdk with help sencha cmd. Add this to `<target name=build` to end of x-sencha-command tag:

```
                    exclude
                        +all
                    and
                    include
                        -namespace=Ext.ux.*
                    optimize
                        -define-rewrite
                    and

                    concatenate
                        +append
                        +yui
                        -output-file=${build.dir}/ext-ux.js
                    and
```

Comment: How to include ux package in build.xml?

Comment: I think (but i'm not tested this) something like this (added to answer)

Comment: Thanks @pvlt , now this ext-ux.js contains only ux components rite? and i use only one component from ux package, is there anyway to exclude remaining components?

Comment: yes, ext-ux.js contains only Ext.ux namespace components. you can check this just removing —compress option and checking file

Comment: yeah i got the uncompressed file as well , but is it ok to edit that? will it not get corrupted?

Comment: In the generated ext-ux file , i cant find livesearchgridpanel class